# Yii framework multi language, multi top level domain

Tags: yii, localization, multilingual

My goal is to have this:

.com/english-urls - English (United States)

.com.br/portuguess-urls - Portuguess (Brazil)

.com.mx/spanish-urls - Spanish (México)

...

I already have working multilingual functionality using this Language Switcher: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/293/manage-target-language-in-multilingual-applications-a-language-selector-widget-i18n/

And URL localization using this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/55/i18n-subdomains-and-url-rules/

Any idea on how to have the multi top level domain functionality?

Thanks in advance to contribute to Yii development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can approach this.

1. Parameterized host names. See the guide for details on how to set it up: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#parameterizing-hostnames
2. Use environment variables set as part of your web server depending on the domain name being used.

I've done #1 in the past and it works pretty well. One nasty side effect comes up if you have a site that runs with SSL but your devs work with non-SSL machines. Parameterized host names require the full http:// or https:// as part of the URL rule unless you extend CUrlManager.

Another bug I hit recently occurs if you use parameterized hostnames *AND* a baseUrl (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3520). Probably not something to worry about, but an FYI that it is there.

Which is why the idea of using environment variables intrigues me. You might be able to load only rule sets that match your given language, etc. but I haven't personally built a system using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a solution!

Using this class: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/55/i18n-subdomains-and-url-rules/

1.- Define your top level domains list.

public $domainList = array('www.example.com.mx' => 'es', 'www.example.com' => 'en');

2.- Comment the unnesesary code.

3.- Detect SERVER_NAME and save as activeLanguage.

$languageCode = $this->domainList[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']];

$this->activeLanguage = $this->isSupportedLanguage($languageCode);

3.- Create the links in your header or main.

Thanks to twitter.com/atrandafir and [acorncom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334913/acorncom) for contribute!